# Removing replication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, replication

I want to remove replication as we are not going to use it further. I want to know what steps should we follow to remove the replication like:

1. Which jobs to stop
2. Delete subscription and publisher

...and any other things to consider. I am doing it for the first time, so I need help regarding this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to totally remove replication from the server.

There are a number of tools you can use, as outlined here for limited dismantling of replication.

[Removing Replication](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152757(v=sql.105).aspx)

If you just want to **strip all replication from the server**, you can apparently use `sp_removedreplication` on each database that needs to have replication dropped.

[sp_removedbreplication (Transact-SQL) on the appropriate database](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188734(v=sql.105).aspx)

The code is simple.  Here is the MSDN example code:

```
-- Remove replication objects from the subscription database on MYSUB.
DECLARE @subscriptionDB AS sysname
SET @subscriptionDB = N'AdventureWorks2008R2Replica'

-- Remove replication objects from a subscription database (if necessary).
USE master
EXEC sp_removedbreplication @subscriptionDB
GO
```

Comment: Thanx @RLF for you help